# Extra period after et collab. (french et al.) in francais.bst

Tags: bibtex

I am using the francais.bst bibliography style and there is an extra period after the "et collab." (the french equivalent to "et al.") in the bibliography entries. When citing in the text, there is a single period as it should be.

[image: Example of a bibliography entry with et collab..]

The francaisbst.tex file defines `\def\bbletal{et~collab.}` so I guess the problem is somewhere in francais.bst but I am not familiar enough with the language used there. The format.names function is defined as:

```
FUNCTION {format.names}
{ 'bibinfo :=
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$ {    
  's :=
  "" 't :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr
      duplicate$ #1 >
        { "{f.~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}" }
        { "{vv~}{ll}{, f.}{, jj}" }
      if$
      format.name$
      bibinfo bibinfo.check
      't :=
      nameptr #1 >
        {
          namesleft #1 >
            { ", " * t * }
            {
              s nameptr "{ll}" format.name$ duplicate$ "others" =
            { 't := }
                { pop$ }
              if$
              t "others" =
                {
                  " " * bbl.etal *
                }
                {
                  bbl.and
                  space.word * t *
                }
              if$
            }
          if$
        }
            't
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
  } if$
}
```

Thanks!

Edit: I do not get the same problem with initials:
[image: Example of a bibliography entry with name ending with an initial.]

I saw the question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165222/bibtex-how-to-get-rid-of-a-period-after-author-initial), but it does not correspond exactly to my problem.

Edit2: MWE

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\documentclass[french]{article}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{andrieu2011nonlinear,
  author    = {Andrieu, Christophe and Jasra, Ajay and Doucet, Arnaud and Del Moral, Pierre and others},
  title     = {{O}n {N}onlinear {M}arkov {C}hain {M}onte {C}arlo},
  year      = {2008},
  journal   = {Bernoulli},
  publisher = {Bernoulli Society for Mathematical Statistics and Probability},
}
@Article{bai2009simultaneous,
  author  = {Bai, Yan},
  title   = {{S}imultaneous {D}rift {C}onditions for {A}daptive {M}arkov {C}hain {M}onte {C}arlo {A}lgorithms},
  journal = {Preprint},
  year    = {2009},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[english, frenchb]{babel}
\bibliographystyle{francais}
\begin{document}
\cite{andrieu2011nonlinear}
\cite{bai2009simultaneous}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Output of MWE :

[image: MWE]

Source of the bst file: https://ctan.org/pkg/francais-bst

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Instead of posting a fragment of the `.bst` file, could you please edit your question to include a minimal compilable document that shows how you're producing the bibliography.  It would be helpful also to include a sample `.bib` item. For example, the default form of the bibliography with `francais.bst` seems to be to use all authors in the bibliography.

Comment: Thanks for adding the example. Personally I think adding "and others" to the `.bib` file is completely wrong, but I understand that the `.bst` is set up to handle things that way. `.bib` files should contain all the relevant authors and the `.bst` should be responsible for determining if and where the `et al.` cutoff is.

Comment: Would you suggest simply omitting the "and others" ?

Comment: Yes, but then what you should have in your `.bib` file is the complete list of authors, not a subset of them.

Comment: Ok, great! Thank you for the observation, I think it will be simpler than trying to make the `.bst` work.

Comment: I'll add an answer to that effect. I'll also make some other comments about your `.bib` entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct solution to this problem is really to *not* use "others" in the `.bib` file to begin with. Instead you should add all names to the `.bib` file and let the `.bst` file do the work of figuring out how to truncate references. The `francais.bst` file does this incorrectly, because it assumes you will use "others" in the `.bib` file, but this makes your `.bib` file unusable for styles that require full authors in the bibliography.

There are some other things wrong with your `.bib` entry too. You should not put braces around the first letters of title content words, since captitalization should also be controlled by the `.bst` file not the `.bib` file. The title should be in title case (content words capitalized) and then the bibliography style can decide to lower case them as needed. The only words that should have braces around them (and then around the whole word, not just the initial letter) are proper names or  acronyms that must always be capitalized.

So here's your example with these things fixed. Also, if the article in your `.bib` file is [this one](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bj/1310042853) then it only *has* four authors, so the "et collab." is incorrect in the bibliography anyway.  I've also changed `frenchb` to `french` since `frenchb` is deprecated.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\documentclass[french]{article}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{andrieu2011nonlinear,
  author    = {Andrieu, Christophe and Jasra, Ajay and Doucet, Arnaud and Del Moral, Pierre},
  title     = {On Nonlinear {Markov} Chain {Monte Carlo}},
  year      = {2008},
  journal   = {Bernoulli},
  publisher = {Bernoulli Society for Mathematical Statistics and Probability},
}
@Article{bai2009simultaneous,
  author  = {Bai, Yan},
  title   = {Simultaneous Drift Conditions for Adaptive {Markov} Chain {Monte Carlo} Algorithms},
  journal = {Preprint},
  year    = {2009},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[english, french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\bibliographystyle{francais}
\begin{document}
\cite{andrieu2011nonlinear}
\cite{bai2009simultaneous}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Thank you for all your comments! I trusted blindly the Google Scholar BibTeX citation export and I should have been more careful.

Comment: @SimonFontaine Yeah, Google Scholar `bibtex` is really bad. I use https://www.doi2bib.org/ which is generally quite reliable for anything that has a DOI.